# Get value from Firebase using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I tried to retrieve data with the following manner but it didn't work: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): snapshot.val is not a function. (In 'snapshot.val()', 'snapshot.val' is undefined)`

```
var companyScore, userScore;

            firebaseApp.firestore().collection('JobPosting')
            .doc(postId).get().then(snapshot => {
                console.log("Snapshot");
                console.log(snapshot);
                companyScore = snapshot.val().score;
              });
            firebaseApp.firestore().collection('people')
            .doc(currentUser.uid).get().then(snapshot => {
                userScore = snapshot.val().score;
              });
```

I guess I need a solution to get the snapshot data (supposedly a json or hash table), so that I can get the value under the index of `score`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.data()` and not `.val()`

Therefore, the updated code will be like this:

```js
var companyScore, userScore;

            firebaseApp.firestore().collection('JobPosting')
            .doc(postId).get().then(snapshot => {
                console.log("Snapshot");
                console.log(snapshot);
                companyScore = snapshot.data().score;
              });
            firebaseApp.firestore().collection('people')
            .doc(currentUser.uid).get().then(snapshot => {
                userScore = snapshot.data().score;
              });
```

Link to the official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: It worked partly, but I met a new issue: `snapshot.data().score` or `snapshot.data()['score']` doesn't retrieve anything but NaN, though my firebase has already had the key `score`.

Comment: Try `console.log`ing the data and see what are you getting

Comment: My fault there, buddy. I figured out that it's because of the asynchronized nature of firebase. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome buddy! Sometimes mistakes happen. I think you should go through the example codes given in the docs to refresh your knowledge about using the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a document from Firestore returns a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) which does not have a `.val()` method on it. (That method exists on Realtime Database's [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)).

Try refactoring your code to:

```
firebaseApp.firestore().collection('JobPosting').doc(postId).get().then(snapshot => {
  console.log("Snapshot", snapshot);
  companyScore = snapshot.data().score;
});
```

The data method:

> Retrieves all fields in the document as an Object. Returns 'undefined' if the document doesn't exist.